# How to resize Listbox.ItemTemplate -columns

Tags: wpf, listbox

I'm playing around with ListBox control in WPF.
My ItemsSource-viewmodel has three properties to show in the listbox.
For that, I created a DataTemplate, including a grid, with three columns.
Seems that this isn't the best approach for showing a bunch of data, that are very different in length.
I get different size of columns for every field, depending on the length, if I don't set the width to a fixed value.
My dream is a kind of table inside the listbox, that resizes the columns automatically, if the window and with that, the listbox is resized.

What is the best apporach for such datatemplates?

My actual ListBox:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Generators}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="viewmodels:GeneratorListItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding GeneratorType}" Margin="5, 1, 1, 0" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Specs}" Margin="5 1 1 0" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ControlUnit}" Margin="5 1 1 0" />

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

With `*` as width of columns, the content looks very ugly and chaotic, so I tried to use fixed columnwidth. But that isn't so nice when the listbox is resized.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` and `SharedSizeGroup` solved my problem:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Generators}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="viewmodels:GeneratorListItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding GeneratorType}" Margin="5, 1, 1, 0" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Specs}" Margin="5 1 1 0" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ControlUnit}" Margin="5 1 1 0" />

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: You can use `<ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>` to define a ration between the columns.

Comment: Thank you for that Link `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` was the solution.